# Evaluate $\iint_{R} x y \,d x \,d y$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, jacobian

> Using the change of variable evaluate $\iint_{R} x y\ dx\ dy,$ when the region $R$ is bounded by the curves $x y=1, x y=3, y=3 x, y=5 x$ in the $1^{\text {st }}$ quadrant.

---

Then transformation domain is $\mathrm{D}=\{(\mathrm{u}, \mathrm{v}): 1 \leq u \leq 3,3 \leq v \leq 5\}$
$\therefore \mathrm{y}=\sqrt{u v}, x=\sqrt{\frac{u}{v}}$
Jacobian of the transformation is

$$
\begin{split}
\mathrm{J}
 &= \left|\begin{array}{ll}\frac{1}{\sqrt{v}} \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{u}} & \sqrt{u}\left(-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{v \sqrt{v}}\right) \\ \sqrt{v} \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{u}} & \sqrt{u} \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{v}}\end{array}\right|
=\frac{1}{4 v}+\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{v}=\frac{1}{2 v}\\
\mathrm{I}
 &= \int_3^5 \int_1^3 u \cdot \frac{1}{2 v}\ du\ dv
  = \left[\left[\frac{u^2}{4}\right]_1^3[\ln v]_3^5
  = \log \left(\frac{25}{9}\right)\right.
\end{split}
$$

It's the answer I got from a solution book. But I am unable to understand that. Can anybody help me out.TIA.

Comment: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: transformation domain and jacobian part

Answer (score 1):

You are told to integrate over a certain region $R$ in the $(x,y)$-plane. This region $R$ is bounded by the hyperbolic arcs $xy=1$ and $xy=3$, and by segments on the lines $ y=3x$ and $y=5x$.

**Draw a figure!**

These data suggest to consider the new variables
$$u:= xy,\qquad v:={y\over x}\ .\tag{1}$$
These variables are bound by
$$1\leq u\leq3,\qquad 3\leq v\leq5\ ,$$
hence have a rectangular domain $R'=[1,3]\times[3,5]$. Furthermore we get from $(1)$ that
$$x=\sqrt{u\over v},\qquad y=\sqrt{uv}\qquad(1\leq u\leq3, \ 3\leq v\leq5)\ .\tag{2}$$
The equations $(2)$ define a function $f:\>(u,v)\mapsto(x,y)$ that maps the domain $R'$ bijectively onto $R$. The latter fact is "obvious" from the figure. It implies that
$$Q:=\int_R x y\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_{R'}\sqrt{u\over v}\>\sqrt{uv}\>J_f(u,v)\>{\rm d}(u,v)=\ldots$$
You have computed $J_f(u,v)={1\over2v}$. When this is correct we therefore obtain
$$Q=\int_1^3\int_3^5{u\over 2v}\>dv\>du=\ldots=\log{25\over9}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $u=xy$ while $v=y/x$, the first two curves are the bound $1\le u\le 3$, while the last two are $3\le v\le5$. Now we just need to rewrite $\underbrace{xy}_u\underbrace{dxdy}_{Jdudv}$, with $J=\frac{1}{2v}$ the [Jacobian determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).